# Lowercase to uppercase with opening new file

Tags: c, file

I tried to change all random lowercase letters to uppercase letters in this program.First of all, I have initialized in lowercase.txt **AkfsASlkALfdk**.Then I read from it and changing all the lowercase letters into capital ones.The problem is,when I opened the **capital.txt** is **ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌAKFSASLKALFDK**.Where did the error come from?I couldn't find it yet and I decided to ask you.

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() 
{
    int i;
    char s[100];
    char k[100];
FILE *kp;
kp = fopen("lowercase.txt", "r");
if (kp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error in opening file.\n");
    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}
FILE *temp;
temp = fopen("capital.txt", "w");
if (kp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error in opening file.\n");
    system("pause");
    exit(2);
}
    printf("Opening file is successful.\n");


    if (fscanf(kp, "%s", &s) != EOF)
    {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
        if (s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122)
            {
            s[i] -= 32;

            }
        }
    }
fprintf(temp, "%s", k);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)` -- You assume that all lines/words are 100 characters long. That's not true; you must use the real length of the line: `for (i = 0; s[i]; i++)`. The garbage you see is the garbage after the nul terminator `'\0'`.

Comment: You are opening in `temp` but checking `kp`

Comment: You are changing in k but saving s.

Comment: Also, `fscanf(f, "%s", s)`(note that there is not `&` when scanning strings) reads "words", i.e. everything but white space. You lose all white space when writing to the output file.

Comment: Well, Ajay's comment has the real reason: You upper-case `s`, but print `k`, which is a char buffer that has never been initialised. That's garbage right from the start.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I have opened a new file in order to copy the string into that and change it on that file.

Comment: @dozgunay Yes, I understand. The condition to check if the file has opened should be `if ( temp == NULL)` in that case.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I understand my mistakes.I am very pleased from your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues in your code which together cause the issues

1. You are storing the opened FILE* in temp, but checking kp. I think that is because you copy pasted the check from above. Can be easily fixed by changing the variable
2. You perform the capitalization operation outside what was set by scanf. As suggested by @MOehm, change the loop condition to `s[i]`
3. Finally you are converting the string in place in s but are saving k in the file. k is never modified. Change `fprintf(temp, "%s", k);` to `fprintf(temp, "%s", s);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *append(const char *s, char c) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    char buf[len+2];
    strcpy(buf, s);
    buf[len] = c;
    buf[len + 1] = 0;
    return strdup(buf);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char ch;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2)
      return (0);

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *res;
    while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
      res = append(res, ch);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(res))
    {
      if (res[i] >= 97 && res[i] <= 122)
        res[i] = res[i] - 32;
      i++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

here is a quick example

read the file char by char and add each char in a char *. Then for each character lowercase char, sub 32 to get the uppercase char and write it then print. Give the filename as first parameter when you start the programm

Comment: I understand, using pointer and strlen function is the easiest way to complete this programme I guess,isn't it?